# Regex return seven digit number match only

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I've been trying to build a regular expression to extract a 7 digit number from a string but having difficulty getting the pattern correct.

Example string - `WO1519641 WO1528113TB WO1530212 TB`

Example return - `1519641, 1528113, 1530212`

My code I'm using in Excel is...

```
Private Sub Extract7Digits()
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim Myrange As Range

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A300")

    For Each c In Myrange
        strPattern = "\D(\d{7})\D"
        'strPattern = "(?:\D)(\d{7})(?:\D)"
        'strPattern = "(\d{7}(\D\d{7}\D))"

        strInput = c.Value

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.test(strInput) Then
            Set matches = regEx.Execute(strInput)
            For Each Match In matches
                s = s & " Word: " & Match.Value & " "
            Next
                c.Offset(0, 1) = s
            Else
                s = ""
        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

I've tried all 3 patterns in that code but I end up getting a return of `O1519641, O1528113T, O1530212` when using `"\D(\d{7})\D"`. As I understand now the `()` doesn't mean anything because of the way I am storing the matches while I initially thought they meant that the expression would *return* what was inside the `()`.

I've been testing things on http://regexr.com/ but I'm still unsure of how to get it to allow the number to be inside the string as `WO1528113TB` is but only return the numbers.  Do I need to run a RegEx on the returned value of the RegEx to exclude the letters the second time around?

Comment: Do you need your expected result is just a single string or an array/collection?

Comment: I can work with either one but ideally I need to return the largest number out of the collection.

Comment: Well, try `strPattern = "(?:^|\D)(\d{7})(?!\d)"` and then `s = s & " Word: " & match.SubMatches(0) & " "`. The point is that you need to iterate all submatches using `match.SubMatches(0)` and then you may check which is the largest.

Comment: For the pattern can you not just use `\d{7}`?

Comment: @SJR: Unless there are 8+ digit chunks that should not be matched.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that works but I'm unsure of how, could you change it to an answer and elaborate on the pattern?

Comment: @SJR the reasoning for the \D was to not extract 7 digits from a larger number.

Comment: Both - ah, ok I thought the OP was looking at at seven digit numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using the following pattern:

```
strPattern = "(?:^|\D)(\d{7})(?!\d)"
```

Then, you will be able to access capturing group #1 contents (i.e. the text captured with the `(\d{7})` part of the regex) via `match.SubMatches(0)`, and then you may check which value is the largest.

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:^|\D)` - a non-capturing group (does not create any submatch) matching the start of string (`^`) or a non-digit (`\D`)
- `(\d{7})` -  Capturing group 1 matching 7 digits
- `(?!\d)` - a negative lookahead failing the match if there is a digit immediately after the 7 digits.

Comment: Nice explanation.